# Extending length of column pushes down rows in Bootstrap horizontal form

Tags: angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I have a basic horizontal form written in Angular that uses bootstrap components. 
My problem is that there is a "Comment field" that pushes down the fields the next column over.

[image: example of comment field pushing down third column]
You can see it in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gu1sz12L/4/

```
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label for="comment" class="col-md-4 control-label">Comment:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="10" id="comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I thought about splitting the form into two sections, one horizontal form on the left with the first two columns, and one on the right with the last two columns. However, I think it's possible that this approach will mess up the tabbing of fields.

How can I keep the Comment field separated into its own column?

Comment: It looks like it's due to the way you're wrapping stuff in non-responsive <div> tags. I think you should try to restructure your <div>s and bootstrap classes.

Comment: @Lex I fixed the nested <div>s and am still having the same problem : http://jsfiddle.net/k0c0e68n/